# RSolve with integrations

Tags: equation-solving, recursion, difference-equations, integral-equations

I want to solve this question with Mathematica.

$$T_0(t)=c(t),\quad T_n(t)=a\int_0^t T_{n-1}(s)\, \mathrm{d}s+b(t).$$

Is it possible to solve $T_n(t)$ with `RSolve`? Or is there some other solution?

Here is my code:

```
RSolve[{T[n, t] == a Integrate[T[n - 1, s], {s, 0, t}] + b[t], T[0, t] == c[t]}, T[n, t], n]
```

Comment: What did you try? What was the result?

Comment: @m_goldberg http://i.imgur.com/AsTKiSS.png

Comment: Please don't post images or links to images. Post code properly formatted with markdown that people can copy from your post and work with.

Comment: `RSolve[{T[n, t] == a Integrate[T[n - 1, s], {s, 0, t}] + b[t], 
  T[0, t] == c[t]}, T[n, t], n]`

Comment: @m_goldberg OK, thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample expressions for `b` and `c`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Can't they be any function?

Comment: Certainly, they can but some choices may permit simple approaches.  May I assume that you want a general solution?  Also, what are you seeking - a general expression for `T[n]` in terms of `b` and `c`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RSolve` cannot handle this problem due to the integrals, although one could imaging discretizing the integrals, if `c[t]` and `b[t]` are smooth enough, and attempting to use `RSolve` on the resulting two-dimension recurrence relation.

However, the problem can be solved analytically by assuming that `T[n_, t_]` takes the form `Integrate[g[n, t, t1] c[t1] + h[n, t, t1] b[t1], {t1, 0, t}]` and deriving `g` and `h` inductively.  After some algebra, the resulting expression is obtained.

```
T[n_, t] := a Integrate[c[t1] (a (t - t1))^(n - 1)/(n - 1)!, {t1, 0, t}] + 
  If[n > 1, a Integrate[b[t1] Exp[a (t - t1)] Gamma[n - 1, a (t - t1)]/(n - 2)!, 
  {t1, 0, t}], 0] + b[t]
```

This formulation can be compared with a direct evaluation of `T[n_, t_]`, based on the expressions in the Question.

```
T[0, t_] := c[t]
T[n_, t_] := a Integrate[T[n - 1, t1], {t1, 0, t}] + b[t]
```

With sample functions,

```
c[t_] = Sin[t];
b[t_] = Exp[-t];
```

both formulations yield, for instance,

```
T[3, t]
(* E^(-t) + a*(1 + a*t + (a^2*t^2)/2 + a^2*(-1 + Cos[t]) + 
   a*(-1 + Cosh[t]) - Cosh[t] + Sinh[t] - a*Sinh[t]) *)
```

I have verified the equality of the two representations up to `n = 20`.

**Addendum: Inductive Proof**

To prove formally that the first expression given above, as requested by the OP, begin with `b[t]` equal to zero and assume that T[n, t] is given by

```
a Integrate[c[t1] (a (t - t1))^(n - 1)/(n - 1)!, {t1, 0, t}]
```

Then, according to the equation in the Question, T[n+1, t] is obtained by a second integration

```
a^2 Integrate[c[t2] (a (t - t1))^(n - 1)/(n - 1)!, {t1, 0, t}, {t2, 0, t1}]
```

Next, reverse the order of integration.

```
a^2 Integrate[c[t2] (a (t - t1))^(n - 1)/(n - 1)!, {t2, 0, t}, {t1, t2, t}]
(* a^2*Integrate[((a*(t - t2))^n*c[t2])/(a*Gamma[1 + n]), {t2, 0, t}] *)
```

which after simplification becomes

```
(* a*Integrate[((a*(t - t2))^n*c[t2])/n !, {t2, 0, t}] *)
```

This is identical to the original expression in this Addendum but with `n` replaced by `n + 1`.  Thus, if the original expression is true for any given `n`, it is true for all larger `n`.  Now, set `n -> 1` in the original expression.

```
(* a Integrate[c[t1], {t1, 0, t}] *)
```

which agrees with the equation in the Question and therefore also is true.  Hence, the original expression in the Addendum is true for all `n > 0`.

Next, consider the effect of `b[t]`.  According to the equations in the Question, T[1, t] becomes

```
a Integrate[c[t1] ((a (t - t1))^(n - 1)/(n - 1)!)/.n -> 1, {t1, 0, t}] + b[t]
```

Similarly, T[2, t] becomes

```
a Integrate[c[t1] ((a (t - t1))^(n - 1)/(n - 1)!)/.n -> 2, {t1, 0, t}] + 
  a Integrate[b[t1] ((a (t - t1))^(n - 1)/(n - 1)!)/.n -> 1, {t1, 0, t}] + b[t]
```

and T[3, t]

```
a Integrate[c[t1] ((a (t - t1))^(n - 1)/(n - 1)!)/.n -> 3, {t1, 0, t}] + 
  a Integrate[b[t1] ((a (t - t1))^(n - 1)/(n - 1)!)/.n -> 2, {t1, 0, t}] + 
  a Integrate[b[t1] ((a (t - t1))^(n - 1)/(n - 1)!)/.n -> 1, {t1, 0, t}] + b[t]
```

etc.  The integrands of the ever-growing number of integrals over `b[t]` can be summed formally according to the formula

```
Sum[x^i/i!, {i, 0, n - 1}]
(* (E^x*Gamma[n, x])/Gamma[n] *)
```

which completes the proof that first expression in the original answer is formally correct.  Of course, the constructive proof given yesterday also is compelling: it visibly gives the correct result for each `n`.

Comment: Is `T[n_, t]` solved by Mathematica of by hand?

Comment: Both representations of `T[n_, t_] ` are in Mathematica code and can be solved using Mathematica. Indeed, I have done so.  Please try them out and let me know what you think.

Comment: `T[n_,t_]` is working, but this may not be what I need. Because I want `n` there. `T[n_,t]` can be a possible answer, but I didn't see how you got it, for example, `after some algebra`.

Comment: Also, I don't agree with you on `T[n_,t]`. Maybe there is some mistake. There will be a $\int_0^{t_1}\int_0^{t_2}\cdots\int_0^{t_n}c(t_n)\, \mathrm{d}t_n \cdots \mathrm{d}t_2\mathrm{d}t_1$ term.

Comment: I can provide the derivation, now that I have a little time.  What do you mean by "this may not be what I need.  Because I want `n` there."?  Also, if this is not what you need, what do you need?  Please be specific.  Finally, with respect to your second comment, just added, my solution give the right answer - correct?  So, it must include the multiple integrals that you just wrote down.  And, in fact it does in both formulations.

Comment: What I want is $T_n$ represented by $n,~c(t),~b(t)$ and integrations.

Comment: I will appreciate it if you tell me how you simplified it to your answer. Then I will know if they are equivalent.

Comment: It is midnight, and I will return to this question later, maybe next morning. I am sure to come back ASAP.

Comment: I can simplify your multiple integral in the comment above (which, incidentally, does not have the correct limits of integration) by interchanging the order of integration, a standard trick in problems like this.  I shall modify my answer later today, so that you have it tomorrow morning, your time.

Comment: I am available now. I am willing to know the standard trick. If a comment is too short to type them, please include it in the answer. Take your time in doing this.

Comment: The Addendum just added provides the formal inductive proof you requested.  The key step is to reverse the order of integration, as shown.  Doing so is a standard trick that often (although certainly not always) simplifies nested integrals. In fact, all integrals except one can be eliminated in this way in the present case, if you choose to nest the integrals as you did in an earlier Comment.

Comment: You are right. By exchanging the order of integration, and by induction, I am able to get your result, or at least know how to get there. Thanks very much.